# mysql query php

Tags: php, mysql, lazy-evaluation

i am sending an email to 1000 people. i have a php send email. it works fine. i was wondering, in my query, how can i send it 100 at time.

is it like this:

```
select * from test limit 0, 100
select * from test limit 100, 100
select * from test limit 200, 100
select * from test limit 300, 100
```

etc...

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Easier to do it in the mail code, and just parse out 100 records at a time. Doing it in the SQL will leave you running a lot more queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the answer to your own question, just try it and see, don't ask, it's just lazy.

Comment: thanks, but i didn't know i answered my own question, thanks, i will try it out now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's right.
But I don't think that it's very useful.
Why you don't use a PEAR Lib like http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue and send all at the same time?